# html5 canvas: maxWidth argument to fillText produces ugly results in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

The maxWidth argument to [fillText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas#fillText%28%29) can be used to restrict the maximum width the text renders into, however, in chrome I sometimes get very odd results. Here is a particularly bad example where I need to restrict the width of the text by just a couple pixels. Above is a call to fillText with no maxWidth specified. The bottom example has a maxWidth. There is too big a space between the "w" and "a". Are there any tricks or workarounds to get better results?

[image: "Iowa" rendered in chrome and firefox]

Here's the code used for the example:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.font="8pt Arial";
ctx.fillText("Iowa", 10, 40);
ctx.fillText("Iowa", 10, 56, 21);
```

(edit: simpler repro)
To repro you can go [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AS9rY/) and look at the bottom right box.

**Update:** The original question stated that there was a problem in firefox as well. That was an error. The issue only seems to be present in chrome.

Comment: Are you familiar with http://jsfiddle.net? It allows you to save JavaScript demos and share them with a link. (However, it seems to be malfunctioning at the moment, at least from where I'm sitting.)

Comment: Thanks, here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AS9rY/)

Comment: FWIW different fonts don't seem to have the same issue. I tried out Calibri and it smooths out a lot better.

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome 23 and 25 on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that maxWidth performs scaling on the rendered text, but most text doesn't scale very well to non-integer sizes...  Basically, if you ask for an 7.9px font things won't fit the pixel grid well and will look ugly.

In terms of avoiding it... apart from using a higher DPI display (not really under your control, I know), there's not that much you can do short of avoiding the API.  :(

Comment: maxWidth does not scale the text. You can set a small maxWidth and see the text gets squished horizontally, but not vertically. maxWidth should effect font layout like hinting and kerning. Most of the time it does fine. Here it performs particularly badly. There are many blank pixels between "w" and "a", so it's not clearly hinting that is looking to hit pixel boundaries.

Comment: Looking at the source at least in Firefox it's doing a post-rasterization horizontal scale, so you're right that my comments about a smaller font-size are off.  That said, I can't reproduce the extra pixels between 'w' and 'a' on your fiddle, but I'm on a hi-dpi display...

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks for taking a deep look! You are right that I can't repro it in firefox, I must have remembered wrong, as I develop mostly in chrome. I will update the question. Sorry for the error.